# LGPL Software Rental

Tags: lgpl

Can proprietary software which makes use of LGPLv3 libraries be leased to users for a period of time in exchange for a fee?

If the user modifies the program to allow relinking with altered LGPL DLLs, is he entitled to continue using the modified software (which would include the proprietary software) after the lease period has ended?

Answer (score 2):

The only requirements that the LGPL effectively places on the proprietary software are that the users must be allowed and able to replace the LGPL portion of the product and that they must be made aware of those rights.

There is nothing in the LGPL that forbids a time-limited license or contract on the proprietary part of the product. This also means that you cannot extend (one-sided) the time limit on the product by just replacing the LGPL code.

Comment: If the software is leased to a company, does the right to replace the LGPL code belong to the company, or the employee using the software?

Comment: @19172281, I believe it is the company, but the employees are probably seen as an integral part of it.